# Spring mvc - Querydsl: Cant use distinct with an orderBy distance

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot, querydsl

I am currently trying to build a paginated request for a REST webservice under Spring boot 1.2.2. I am using 'com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.6.2'.

Here is the code i am trying to run:

```
 public QueryPage<Merchant> getMerchants(Integer supermerchantId, Geometry point, Double maxDistance,
                                        String keyword, List<Integer> businessTypes, Integer numPage,
                                        Integer sizePage) {

    QMerchant merchant = QMerchant.merchant;
    QMerchantBusinessType merchantBusinessType= QMerchantBusinessType.merchantBusinessType;

    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    query = query.from(merchant)
            .innerJoin(merchant.merchantBusinessTypes, merchantBusinessType);

    // Master merchant quickFix
    query = query.where(merchant.idSupermerchant.isNotNull());

    if (supermerchantId!=null){
        query = query.where(merchant.idSupermerchant.mercId.eq(supermerchantId));
    }

    if(point != null && maxDistance != null){
        query = query.where(merchant.point.distance(point).lt(maxDistance));
    }

    if(keyword!=null){
        query = query.where(merchant.mercName.containsIgnoreCase(keyword));
    }
    if(businessTypes!=null){
        query = query.where(merchantBusinessType.businessType.id.in(businessTypes).and(merchantBusinessType.merchant.eq(merchant)));
    }

    QueryPage<Merchant> res = new QueryPage<>();
    JPAQuery queryCount = query.clone(entityManager);
    res.setTotalElements(queryCount.distinct().count());

    if(point != null) {
        LOGGER.debug(point.toString());
        query = query.orderBy(merchant.point.distance(point).asc());
    } else {
        query = query.orderBy(merchant.mercName.asc());
    }

    Long offset = new Long((numPage) * sizePage);

    query = query.distinct();
    query = query.offset(offset).limit(sizePage);   // distinct()

    LOGGER.debug("=== QUERY:");
    LOGGER.debug(query.toString());
    List<Merchant> merchants = query.list(merchant);

    res.setContent(merchants);
    res.setPageNumber(numPage);
    res.setPageSize(sizePage);

    return res;
}
```

To avoid returning the same row several times, i put a "query.distinct" which works on certains conditions:

```
        if(point != null) {
        LOGGER.debug(point.toString());
        query = query.orderBy(merchant.point.distance(point).asc());
    } else {
        query = query.orderBy(merchant.mercName.asc());
    }
```

I think that the issue is regarding that condition. The idea is that if the user gave to me coordinates, i have to be able to order my merchants by distance ASC.

If the point is NULL, there is no issue, my merchants are ordered by name ASC. But if the point contains coordinates, i have that error:

```
2015-07-20 17:36:58.363 ERROR 5676 --- [nio-8180-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERREUR: pour SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY, les expressions doivent apparaÃ®tre dans la liste SELECT


2015-07-20 17:36:58.375 DEBUG 5676 --- [nio-8180-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:231)
```

If i print my query, its gave to me:

```
    select distinct merchant
from Merchant merchant
  inner join merchant.merchantBusinessTypes as merchantBusinessType
where merchant.idSupermerchant is not null
order by distance(merchant.point, ?1) asc
```

Which seems correct to me. We are using PostgresSQL with spatial database. The thing is if i remove the ".distinct()" from the query, there is no issue but duplicated merchants...

Does somebody familiar with that library have an idea? I am stuck with it and i have no idea apart from recode this query in pure HQL :)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try Querydsl 3.6.5 as well?

Comment: Hi Timo. I've just tried with Querydsl 3.6.5 but i have the same issue. Maybe its a limitation of the framework... I cant find on the internet an example of a distinct with an order by 'distance'.

The thing is that the "distinct" is needed here because of the join on the 'merchantBusiness' of the merchants

Comment: The exception comes from the database, so you will need to take that restriction from PostgreSQL into account.

Comment: What do you mean by restriction from PGSql account? I dont know where looking for, i was thinking that my query was wrong...

Comment: For select distinct the order by arguments need to appear in the select list